# Carthage Bootstrap Build Fails "exit code 1"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The version of swift on my machine 5.0.1. The swift version of the project is 4.0.

My xcode version is 10.4

I run `carthage bootstrap --platform ios` in the root directory.

```
*** Checking out CocoaAsyncSocket at "7.6.3"
*** Checking out papertraillumberjack at "0.1.8"
*** Checking out AFNetworking at "3.2.1"
*** Checking out fmdb at "2.6"
*** Checking out objective-c at "v4.8.1"
*** Checking out CocoaLumberjack at "3.4.2"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/7m/bb7zj_yj0_zfgjvv3lgntr040000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.wjVbNA.log
*** Downloading CocoaAsyncSocket.framework binary at "Version 7.6.3"
*** Building scheme "AFNetworking iOS" in AFNetworking.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "CocoaLumberjack-iOS" in Lumberjack.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "CocoaLumberjackSwift-iOS" in Lumberjack.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "FMDB iOS" in fmdb.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "Framework (iOS)" in PubNub.xcworkspace
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 1:
    /usr/bin/xcrun dsymutil /Users/benjaminlee/repositories/glass_planner/glass-planner/Carthage/Build/iOS/PubNub.framework/PubNub -o /Users/benjaminlee/repositories/glass_planner/glass-planner/Carthage/Build/iOS/PubNub.framework.dSYM

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/7m/bb7zj_yj0_zfgjvv3lgntr040000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.wjVbNA.log
```

This seems to suggest that perhaps it failed while building scheme "Framework ()iOS" in PubNub.

I go down to the bottom of the log, these are the last lines:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/benjaminlee/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.3_10G8/objective-c/v4.8.1/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/PubNub.framework

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved: https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/how-to-carthage-efficiently-4913b8378898

`carthage update --no-use-binaries --platform iOS`

Did the trick. Now builds successfully.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't solve. nerdycat "Cupcake" framework tried..

Comment: Try bootstraping them.

```carthage bootstrap --no-use-binaries --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS```